# Oracle query by date range but grab subsequent records outside this range if needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a db table of employee timeclock data that I want to query on a per day basis. However, when an employee's work shift straddles midnight the query misses transactions needed to determine the total hours for that employee.

```
ID NUMBER (PK)
EmpId VARCHAR
TransActType VARCHAR
Start TIMESTAMP
Account VARCHAR

1   EmpA ClockIn  7/7/20 8am  Account1
2   EmpB ClockIn  7/7/20 9am  Account7
3   EmpC ClockIn  7/7/20 9am  Account1
4   EmpA Switch   7/7/20 10am Account3
5   EmpA Switch   7/7/20 11am Account6
6   EmpC Switch   7/7/20 1pm  Account4
7   EmpC ClockOut 7/7/20 3pm 
8   EmpD ClockIn  7/7/20 5pm  Account5
9   EmpD Switch   7/7/20 6pm  Account6
10  EmpB ClockOut 7/7/20 6pm
11  EmpD Switch   7/7/20 7pm  Account4
12  EmpA ClockOut 7/7/20 8pm
13  EmpD Switch   7/8/20 1am  Account3
14  EmpD ClockOut 7/8/20 2am
15  EmpA ClockIn  7/8/20 8am  Account1
...
```

My query for grabbing labor for 7/7/20 is

```
SELECT * FROM labor li where li.start between 7/7/20 12 am and 7/7/20 11:59 pm order by empId, start
```

and would only grab records 1-12 but should also grab 13 and 14.

My application code calculates Account duration charged by each employee for the day by looping over query results and diffing start times for sequential employee transactions.

Without records 13 and 14 I cannot determine account4 and account3 duration for employee D.

Perhaps my db design is flawed in that I only store the start time for the transaction and then compute the duration using application code logic.  I decided to design it that way so that if records are moved/inserted/deleted I would have less chance of individual persisted employee labor items overlapping if End times were persisted too.  The sample of labor data above shows that employees can change accounts throughout the day and have multiple labor transactions per day.

I am hoping for a query that could look ahead in time on a per employee basis and if the last transaction of that employee is not a "ClockOut" for the timestamp range, keep grabbing records until one is found.

On the same token I cannot have the first transaction of that employee be the ClockOut from the previous day.

If these queries are next to impossible and the DB design should be changed then I'd like to know that.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the output you hope to see for that data. (And your query doesn't have actual dates; and probably is supposed to go to 11:59pm?) Is there a limit on how far ahead you'd want to look? And which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: If your date range were 7/8/20, would you want records 13 and 14 returned? I assume not, but you say "I cannot have the first transaction of that employee be the ClockOut from the previous day" and 13 is a checkin.

Comment: @AlexPoole you were correct I had a typo on the time, should be 11:59 PM and those dates, yes, syntax not correct but just to get get the gist.  The records I would want are 1-14. I can edit and summarize if you want further clarification.  I want to look ahead only as far as their last clockout for the day period.  If a ClockIn starts on Monday but last transaction on Monday is not a ClockOut, then go into Tuesday until you find a ClockOut

Comment: @EdmCoff  I corrected my data sample.  We technically have another Enum called Switch, where the user is on the clock but they switch accounts.  So no I would not want to pick up 13 and 14 if the day was 7/8/20

Comment: A lot of great responses I will need some time to digest them all.  I'm surprised no one suggested my db design was flawed and I should persist the end time with the start time on each labor transaction.

Answer (score 1):

*`I am hoping for a query that could look ahead in time on a per employee basis and if the last transaction of that employee is not a "ClockOut" for the timestamp range, keep grabbing records until one is found.`*

```
with 
  dates(d1, d2) as (select date '2020-07-07', date '2020-07-08' from dual), 
  main as (select id, empid, transacttype, start_, account, 
                  max(transacttype) keep (dense_rank last order by start_) 
                  over (partition by empid) mtt
           from li join dates on d1 <= start_ and start_ < d2),
  miss as (select empid, max(id) mnid from main where mtt = 'ClockIn' group by empid),
  cout as (select empid, min(id) mxid 
            from li join dates on start_ >= d2 join miss using (empid) 
            where transacttype = 'ClockOut' 
            group by empid) 
select id, empid, transacttype, start_, account from main union all
select li.id, li.empid, li.transacttype, li.start_, li.account from li
  join miss on li.empid = miss.empid and li.id > mnid
  join cout on li.empid = cout.empid and li.id < mxid
  order by empid, start_
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66e2c41ac877f31b00f60925736b3e71)

This query works as you said. I find all data for that period, and also find last value of transacttype. If it is not `ClockOut` then in next steps I look for `min(id)` for missing employees from next day(s). Finally union of main data and missing.

Be careful, because in your examples sometimes it is `Clockout`, sometimes `ClockOut`. You can use `upper()` or something if it happens in your real data.

If you don't want to rely on `id`, but rather on dates, you can use *date* version of above query:

```
with 
  dates(d1, d2) as (select date '2020-07-07', date '2020-07-08' from dual), 
  main as (select id, empid, transacttype, start_, account, 
                  max(transacttype) keep (dense_rank last order by start_) 
                  over (partition by empid) mtt
           from li join dates on d1 <= start_ and start_ < d2),
  miss as (select empid, max(start_) mnst from main where mtt = 'ClockIn' group by empid),
  cout as (select empid, min(start_) mxst 
            from li join dates on start_ >= d2 join miss using (empid) 
            where transacttype = 'ClockOut' 
            group by empid) 
select id, empid, transacttype, start_, account from main union all
select li.id, li.empid, li.transacttype, li.start_, li.account from li
  join dates on start_ >= d2
  join cout on li.empid = cout.empid and li.start_ <= mxst
  order by empid, start_
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3804303161d12fdd540120295321087b)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you could use `match_recognize()` to track the clock-in/switch/clock-out, and then filter based on the clock-in time:

```
select id, empid, transacttype, start_time, account
from labor
match_recognize (
  partition by empid
  order by start_time
  measures
    first(start_time) as grp_clockin
  all rows per match
  after match skip past last row
  pattern (clockin switch* clockout*)
  define
    clockin as clockin.transacttype = 'ClockIn',
    switch as switch.transacttype = 'Switch',
    clockout as clockout.transacttype = 'ClockOut'
)
where grp_clockin >= date '2020-07-07'
and grp_clockin < date '2020-07-08'
order by empid, grp_clockin, start_time;
```

```
ID | EMPID | TRANSACTTYPE | START_TIME          | ACCOUNT 
-: | :---- | :----------- | :------------------ | :-------
 1 | EmpA  | ClockIn      | 2020-07-07 08:00:00 | Account1
 4 | EmpA  | Switch       | 2020-07-07 10:00:00 | Account3
 5 | EmpA  | Switch       | 2020-07-07 11:00:00 | Account6
12 | EmpA  | ClockOut     | 2020-07-07 20:00:00 | null    
 2 | EmpB  | ClockIn      | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | Account7
10 | EmpB  | ClockOut     | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | null    
 3 | EmpC  | ClockIn      | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | Account1
 6 | EmpC  | Switch       | 2020-07-07 13:00:00 | Account4
 7 | EmpC  | ClockOut     | 2020-07-07 15:00:00 | null    
 8 | EmpD  | ClockIn      | 2020-07-07 17:00:00 | Account5
 9 | EmpD  | Switch       | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | Account6
11 | EmpD  | Switch       | 2020-07-07 19:00:00 | Account4
13 | EmpD  | Switch       | 2020-07-08 01:00:00 | Account3
14 | EmpD  | ClockOut     | 2020-07-08 02:00:00 | null
```

As the filter happens late you can use an inline view to narrow it down, at least to a minimum date/time:

```
select id, empid, transacttype, start_time, account
from (
  select *
  from labor
  where start_time >= date '2020-07-07'
)
match_recognize (
  partition by empid
  order by start_time
  measures
    first(start_time) as grp_clockin
  all rows per match
  after match skip past last row
  pattern (clockin switch* clockout*)
  define
    clockin as clockin.transacttype = 'ClockIn',
    switch as switch.transacttype = 'Switch',
    clockout as clockout.transacttype = 'ClockOut'
)
where grp_clockin >= date '2020-07-07'
and grp_clockin < date '2020-07-08'
order by empid, grp_clockin, start_time;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ecf06d3735f87b939dfadb442f6ec7a)

You could also then optionally pick a maximum range if you can come up with a sensible one, say excluding anything more than a day later:

```
select id, empid, transacttype, start_time, account
from (
  select *
  from labor
  where start_time >= date '2020-07-07'
  and start_time < date '2020-07-09'
)
...
```

---

> My application code calculates Account duration charged by each employee for the day by looping over query results and diffing start times for sequential employee transactions

If I understand what you're doing, you could do all of that in the query too:

```
select empid, grp_start_time, grp_end_time, grp_account,
  (grp_end_time - grp_start_time) * interval '1' day as elapsed
from labor
match_recognize (
  partition by empid
  order by start_time
  measures
    first(start_time) as grp_start_time,
    first(account) as grp_account,
    final last(start_time) as grp_end_time
  one row per match
  after match skip to last grp_end
  pattern (grp_start grp_end)
  define
    grp_start as grp_start.transacttype in ('ClockIn', 'Switch'),
    grp_end as grp_end.transacttype in ('Switch', 'ClockOut')
)
where grp_start_time >= date '2020-07-07'
and grp_start_time < date '2020-07-08'
order by empid, grp_start_time;
```

```
EMPID | GRP_START_TIME      | GRP_END_TIME        | GRP_ACCOUNT | ELAPSED                      
:---- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :---------- | :----------------------------
EmpA  | 2020-07-07 08:00:00 | 2020-07-07 10:00:00 | Account1    | +000000000 02:00:00.000000000
EmpA  | 2020-07-07 10:00:00 | 2020-07-07 11:00:00 | Account3    | +000000000 01:00:00.000000000
EmpA  | 2020-07-07 11:00:00 | 2020-07-07 20:00:00 | Account6    | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000
EmpB  | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | Account7    | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000
EmpC  | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | 2020-07-07 13:00:00 | Account1    | +000000000 04:00:00.000000000
EmpC  | 2020-07-07 13:00:00 | 2020-07-07 15:00:00 | Account4    | +000000000 02:00:00.000000000
EmpD  | 2020-07-07 17:00:00 | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | Account5    | +000000000 01:00:00.000000000
EmpD  | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | 2020-07-07 19:00:00 | Account6    | +000000000 01:00:00.000000000
EmpD  | 2020-07-07 19:00:00 | 2020-07-08 01:00:00 | Account4    | +000000000 06:00:00.000000000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5265a452324e3683819e0d282e70947b)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to offset the days, so the start somewhere between 2:00 a.m. and 8 :00 a.m.  Can't tell where exactly, so let's say 5:00 a.m.

Just subtract 5 hours for the date comparison.  Either:

```
where li.start - interval '5' hour >= date '2020-07-07' and 
      li.start - interval '5' hour < date '2020-07-08'
```

Or, in a more index friendly fashion:

```
where li.start >= date '2020-07-07' + interval '5' hour 
      li.start < date '2020-07-08' + interval '5' hour
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8d8c/7)

I'm not confident this is the best solution, but maybe you could use it to build your actual solution off of. Possibly Ponder Stibbons answer would be better than this if adapted to address the requirements clarification from the comments ("So no I would not want to pick up 13 and 14 if the day was 7/8/20").

```
WITH
erange AS
(
 SELECT lii.EmpId, lii."Start", MIN(lio."Start") as "End"
 FROM labor lii INNER JoIN labor lio
  ON lii.EmpId = lio.EmpId
 WHERE lii.TransActType='ClockIn'
  AND lio.TransActType='ClockOut'
  AND lii."Start" < lio."Start"
 GROUP BY lii.EmpId, lii."Start"
)
SELECT li.*
FROM labor li INNER JOIN erange er
 ON li.EmpId = er.EmpId AND li."Start" between er."Start" and er."End"
WHERE er."Start" between date '2020-07-07' and date '2020-07-08'
ORDER BY li.EmpId, li."Start"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple analytic function "FIRST_VALUE" for that:

```sql
select li.*
  , first_value(decode(TransActType,'ClockOut',"START") ignore nulls)
       over(partition by EmpId order by "START" rows between current row and unbounded following) ClockOut
from labor li;
```

As you can see it adds new column ClockOut which contains the time of next ClockOut, so you can easily add required data into your query.

Full test case:

```sql
-- sample data:
with labor(ID,EmpId,TransActType,"START",Account) as (
   select 1   ,'EmpA', 'ClockIn ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 8am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account1' from dual union all 
   select 2   ,'EmpB', 'ClockIn ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 9am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account7' from dual union all 
   select 3   ,'EmpC', 'ClockIn ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 9am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account1' from dual union all 
   select 4   ,'EmpA', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 10am','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account3' from dual union all 
   select 5   ,'EmpA', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 11am','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account6' from dual union all 
   select 6   ,'EmpC', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 1pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account4' from dual union all 
   select 7   ,'EmpC', 'ClockOut', to_timestamp('7/7/20 3pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'        ' from dual union all 
   select 8   ,'EmpD', 'ClockIn ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 5pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account5' from dual union all 
   select 9   ,'EmpD', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 6pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account6' from dual union all 
   select 10  ,'EmpB', 'ClockOut', to_timestamp('7/7/20 6pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'        ' from dual union all 
   select 11  ,'EmpD', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/7/20 7pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account4' from dual union all 
   select 12  ,'EmpA', 'ClockOut', to_timestamp('7/7/20 8pm ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'        ' from dual union all 
   select 13  ,'EmpD', 'Switch  ', to_timestamp('7/8/20 1am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account3' from dual union all 
   select 14  ,'EmpD', 'ClockOut', to_timestamp('7/8/20 2am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'        ' from dual union all 
   select 15  ,'EmpA', 'ClockIn ', to_timestamp('7/8/20 8am ','mm/dd/yy hhAM'),'Account1' from dual 
)
--main query:
select li.*
  , first_value(decode(TransActType,'ClockOut',"START") ignore nulls)
       over(partition by EmpId order by "START" rows between current row and unbounded following) ClockOut
from labor li;
```

Results

```
|   ID | EMPI | TRANSACT | START               | ACCOUNT  | CLOCKOUT
| ---- | ---- | -------- | ------------------- | -------- | -------------------
|    1 | EmpA | ClockIn  | 2020-07-07 08:00:00 | Account1 | 2020-07-07 20:00:00
|    4 | EmpA | Switch   | 2020-07-07 10:00:00 | Account3 | 2020-07-07 20:00:00
|    5 | EmpA | Switch   | 2020-07-07 11:00:00 | Account6 | 2020-07-07 20:00:00
|   12 | EmpA | ClockOut | 2020-07-07 20:00:00 |          | 2020-07-07 20:00:00
|   15 | EmpA | ClockIn  | 2020-07-08 08:00:00 | Account1 | 
|    2 | EmpB | ClockIn  | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | Account7 | 2020-07-07 18:00:00
|   10 | EmpB | ClockOut | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 |          | 2020-07-07 18:00:00
|    3 | EmpC | ClockIn  | 2020-07-07 09:00:00 | Account1 | 2020-07-07 15:00:00
|    6 | EmpC | Switch   | 2020-07-07 13:00:00 | Account4 | 2020-07-07 15:00:00
|    7 | EmpC | ClockOut | 2020-07-07 15:00:00 |          | 2020-07-07 15:00:00
|    8 | EmpD | ClockIn  | 2020-07-07 17:00:00 | Account5 | 2020-07-08 02:00:00
|    9 | EmpD | Switch   | 2020-07-07 18:00:00 | Account6 | 2020-07-08 02:00:00
|   11 | EmpD | Switch   | 2020-07-07 19:00:00 | Account4 | 2020-07-08 02:00:00
|   13 | EmpD | Switch   | 2020-07-08 01:00:00 | Account3 | 2020-07-08 02:00:00
|   14 | EmpD | ClockOut | 2020-07-08 02:00:00 |          | 2020-07-08 02:00:00
```